# X509Certificates Lifecycle

Tags: java, security, x509certificate, ca

I have started developing a CA with the bouncy castle library (assume that the operation server is the CA itself)

Can you, please, suggest the detailed (!!!) lifecycle of the certificate processing?

The matter is I've read lots of articles, but all of them describe the general process.

For example, what is the very beginning of aclient/server connection. What must the client give a server to get a certificate? I can use only a subject (a String object like "CN=some cn") to generate a certificate, but the is also a stuff like certificate request. What is the difference (proc and cons)? Or may be it is better to ask the client for a subject, then form a certificate request and provide it to the certificate generation method (actually, I can't see a profit of that variant)...

Comment: Read not articles, but specialized books. There are several books, related to PKI, present on Amazon. First is "RSA Security's OFficial Guide to Cryptography", second one (with more details) is "PKI: Implementing & Managing E-Security".

Comment: Thank you! The problem is I need to present the prototype of the CA soon. After building it. I'll dig into

Answer (score 2):

Refer Book Beginning Cryptography with Java [Wrox 2005]
In chaper no 6 you will get more information about X509Certificate and its uses